# DateInput default parse function

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, admin-on-rest

I wanted to wrap DateInput into MyDateInput with pre-filled parse function argument in order not to repeat `parse={dateParser}` everywhere.

So I created such element:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DateInput } from 'admin-on-rest';
import moment from 'moment';

const dateParser = date => {
    // v is a `Date` object
    if (!(date instanceof Date) || isNaN(date)) return;
    return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

const MyDateInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <DateInput {...props} parse={dateParser} />
    );
};
```

Which did not work as I expected, so from docs I found that I have to do something like this, but source argument not parsed as it has to be:

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';

const MyDateInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <Field name='date' component={DateInput} {...props} parse={dateParser} />
    );
};
```

When I put 2 such inputs into one form it result in merge of input for both of them.
Is there a way to it properly?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? what do you mean by `it results in merge of input for both of them`?

Comment: as mentioned in first answer redux-form stores data by name, so when I set name for Field it takes data from that field from store for all Fields with same name

Answer (score 1):

Redux Form name prop sets the name of the field in the state that the Field Component will affect.

So you need to give a different name prop every time you want to use the Field component.

You can provide name as a prop from the form that is calling the Wrapped DateInput comp make sure it is unique ever time.